# Copy file from flash drive and then execute

Tags: boot

I need to copy a file from a flash disk connected to my Raspberry Pi when it boots and then execute the copied file. The reason for this is because it seems that I cannot execute the file from my USB drive.

What I did was:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and added the following (in order to copy the file from the USB drive to the Pi folder - drive is the USB drive name - and then run the file):

```
cp /media/pi/drive/file /home/pi 
sudo ./home/pi/file &
```

Both commands work when I enter it into terminal but this doesn't execute on startup.

Reason is that should I wish to change the program I can do so on another Pi, copy it onto the USB and restart the Pi to copy/replace the existing file and execute.

Answer (score 2):

Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

It may be possible that the USB drive isn't mounted before executing the commands. I suggest to use a systemd unit file. Just create a new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --full --force edit copyfile.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Copy and execute file from USB drive
After=multi-user.target
RequiresMountsFor=/media/pi/drive

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStartPre=/bin/cp /media/pi/drive/file /home/pi
ExecStart=/home/pi/file

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable copyfile.service
```

Reboot and check with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status copyfile.service
```

Comment: @ChaunBooysen Sorry, but your comments are unreadable. Please edit your question and insert the formated message into it.

Answer (score 1):

/etc/rc.local runs as root so you NEVER need `sudo` in there.

It also runs with a limited environment and /etc as the current working directory. So you can't use relative file names. Use the full path for everything with no strange punctuation.

```
md /media/pi
mount /dev/sda1 /media/pi
cp /media/pi/drive/file /home/pi/script
chmod 755 /home/pi/script
su pi /home/pi/script
```

rc.local runs before the GUI automounter.

Comment: Are you sure that rc.local runs before GUI automounter? systemd does not guarantee this https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/

Comment: @ingo yes I am sure. The GUI can't start before multi-user.target is reached.

Comment: Ah.. OK, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it to work, not sure if it's the most elegant of ways but it works...

Created an extra file with the following and called the file from rc.local

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 30
cp /media/pi/drive/file.sh /home/pi
sudo chmod +x /home/pi/file.sh
/home/pi/file.sh
```

not sure how long to wait but reckoned 30s is ok, it copies the file over, changes to executable and runs it :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the advice to not use rc.local you should note that the /media is NOT automounted until the GUI starts; this is a long time after boot.

Comment: no really much of an answer